# How to query Json into SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, rest

I have a problem. I want to populate a JSON string into a table, however, it only writes me the first row and not the rest. I get the JSON from a rest API.

Below is my code and an excerpt from the JSON file

```
DECLARE @token INT;
DECLARE @ret INT;

DECLARE @url nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @Json2 nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @authheader nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @contentType nvarchar(max);

DECLARE @apiKey_lat nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @apiKey_lot nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @apiKey_start nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @apiKey_end nvarchar(max);

DECLARE @apikey nvarchar(max);


DECLARE @json AS TABLE (Json_Table nvarchar(max))
 

SET @authheader = ''
SET @contentType = 'application/json'




SET @url = ''

EXEC @ret = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @token OUT;
IF @ret <> 0 RAISERROR ('Unable to open HTTP Connection', 10, 1);


EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @url, 'false';
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'authorization', @authheader;
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-type', @contentType;
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'send'

EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'responseText', @Json2 OUTPUT;



INSERT INTO @json (Json_Table) EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'responseText'

SELECT * FROM @json

SELECT * FROM OPENJSON((SELECT * FROM @json))


WITH (
    [parameter] NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.parameter',
    [lat] NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.lat',
    [lon] NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.lon',
    [dates] NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.date',
    [value] NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.value'
) AS MetaData
```

Here is the JSON Snippet:

```json
{"data": [
            {
                "parameter": "t_2m:C",
                "coordinates": [
                    {
                        "lat": 51.123456,
                        "lon": -0.123456,
                        "dates": [
                            {
                                "date": "2021-11-17T12:05:00Z",
                                "value": 10.6
                            },
                            {
                                "date": "2021-11-17T13:05:00Z",
                                "value": 11.4
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
}
```

My Output looks like this:

[image: My Output]

The result should be a table with the values of LAT, LON, DATE, and VALUE from the JSON.

Here is an Example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a967d.png)

Edit:
I also tiredit it with Cross Apply. Didnt worked. Looks like this:

[CROSS_APPLY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfTkH.png)

Here is the codewith Cross Apply:

```
DECLARE @token INT;
DECLARE @ret INT;

DECLARE @url nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @Json2 nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @authheader nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @contentType nvarchar(max);

--Set Parameters
DECLARE @apiKey_lat nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @apiKey_lot nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @apiKey_start nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @apiKey_end nvarchar(max);

DECLARE @apikey nvarchar(max);


DECLARE @json AS TABLE (Json_Table nvarchar(max))

--Set Authentications 

SET @authheader = ''
SET @contentType = 'application/json'




SET @url = ''


EXEC @ret = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @token OUT;
IF @ret <> 0 RAISERROR ('Unable to open HTTP Connection', 10, 1);

EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @url, 'false';
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'authorization', @authheader;
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-type', @contentType;
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'send'

EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'responseText', @Json2 OUTPUT;



INSERT INTO @json (Json_Table) EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'responseText'

SELECT * FROM @json

SELECT * FROM OPENJSON((SELECT * FROM @json))


WITH (
        [data] NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
) AS MetaData



CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([MetaData].[data])
WITH(
    [parameter] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [coordinates] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [lat] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [lon] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [dates] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [value] NVARCHAR(MAX)
) AS Test_Metadata
```

In the SQL query the URL of the rest API and the Authorization header are missing.

Comment: Why are you using those ancient OA objects? What are the results you actually after here?

Comment: Also, the JSON you provide isn't valid. You have nodes and arrays that you don't close. Should it be assumed they you're real JSON is also unfinished?

Comment: [so] is an English Site. Content needs to be in English. That includes the comments.

Comment: I didn't know there was another way except with the OA objects. . The result should be that you have a column for the parameter and for the lat and lon and the date. The JSON is complete. I have copied only a part here. So that one can see all column relevant data.

Comment: So, for the sample data you have provided (which you should make valid) what are you expected results. Include the, in the question. As for the OA objects, they aren't even discussed in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) so I'm not sure *where* you read they you needed to use them. Those objects are there more for compatibility purposes with databases from the mid 2000's than anything else.

Comment: You should use something like Powershell's `Invoke-WebRequest` to download. SQL Server is not a generalized scripting language, do not use it as such. What exactly is your expected output? Also your sample data and the screenshot do not seem to match up, and the JSON you provided is not valid, please fix.

Comment: My Expected Output should be a table with the values of LAT, LON, DATE, and VALUE from the JSON.

Comment: Not a good enough specification for hierarchical data, really. Please mock up a screenshot of exactly what youre expecting your table to look like for the JSON you put in your question

Comment: I've added a Screenshot from the expected Table

Comment: Due to the nested arrays in the JSON you're going to need some cross applies.

Comment: I also tried it with some cross Applies but that didn't work too. the only thing that happened with Cross Applies was that the first row got a value and the rest still haven't. Do I have to do multiple cross replays then? Or how exactly does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use the `sp_OA` procedures, as they are full of bugs, difficult to use, and for compatibility only. SQL Server is not a generalized scripting language, do not use it as such.

Instead use something like Powershell's `Invoke-WebRequest` to download the data, then feed it into SQL Server using `Invoke-SqlCmd` or `Invoke-DbaQuery`.

If you pass it in as a parameter `@json` you can do the following to get your desired result:

```sql
SELECT
  d.parameter,
  coord.lat,
  coord.lon,
  dates.date,
  dates.value
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.data[0]')
  WITH (
    parameter nvarchar(100),
    coordinates nvarchar(max) AS JSON
  ) d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.coordinates)
  WITH (
    lat decimal(9,7),
    lon decimal(9,7),
    dates nvarchar(max) AS JSON
  ) coord
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(coord.dates)
  WITH (
    date datetimeoffset,
    value decimal(18,2)
  ) dates;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bb29e472b194f94f2d7dea2cc2cb121e)

Note how `coordinates` and `dates` is declared `AS JSON`, and then passed into `OPENJSON` again using `CROSS APPLY`.

Comment: I have another question, how can I include the "parameter": "t_2m:C" in the table?

Comment: You would need that third `OPENJSON`, have modified

Comment: @Joo, if the answer worked for you then you should accept it. So someone can use it in the future.